# Why does my cron job to disable Bluetooth after reboot not work?

Tags: bluetooth, cron, reboot

I've noticed that Zorin enables Bluetooth each time I reboot/boot the device, and I don't want that. Note that Bluetooth is always enabled, regardless of whether it was enabled or disabled before the reboot.

Therefore, I created the following cron job:

```
@reboot rfkill unblock bluetooth && /etc/init.d/bluetooth stop
```

Since the command requires sudo access, I used `sudo crontab -e` instead of just `crontab -e`.

Now, while the command works perfectly fine when run manually, the cron job does not work; Bluetooth is still enabled after rebooting.

What's wrong? Thank you!

```
OS: Zorin 16.2 (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)
Codename: Focal
Kernel: 5.15.0-67-generic
```

**Edit:** I followed [@codlord](https://askubuntu.com/users/1061422/codlord)'s advice and put the command into a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail
IFS=$'\n\t'

rfkill unblock bluetooth
/etc/init.d/bluetooth stop
```

Here's my new cronjob:

```
@reboot ~/Applications/bash_scripts/disable_bluetooth.sh > ~/Applications/bash_scripts/disable_bluetooth.log 2>&1
```

However, no such `disable_bluetooth.log` has been created after rebooting the device. It seems like the cron job was not performed at all.

**Edit 2:** After correcting the path to `/home/pixelcode/...`, the log file was indeed created as intended, and it says:

```
rfkill: command not found
```

**Edit 3:** I added the `PATH` to the root crontab using `sudo crontab -e`:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
@reboot /home/pixelcode/Applications/bash_scripts/disable_bluetooth.sh > /home/pixelcode/Applications/bash_scripts/disable_bluetooth.log 2>&1
```

Now the log file says:

```
Stopping bluetooth (via systemctl): bluetooth.service.
```

However, according to the system settings, Bluetooth is still enabled.

[image: the log file next to the system menu, both showing different states of the Bluetooth service]

Comment: cron errors may be shown in the system log but I would suggest you put all your commands into a shell script, make the script executable and then make your cron job: `@reboot /path/to/my/script.bash > /path/to/my/log.log 2>&1` then you can look at the log and see any error messages etc.

Comment: Where did you look for the log file? when you use `~` inside **root's** crontab, `~` will expand to root's home directory (by default, `/root`), not yours. Anyhow, likely `rfkill` is not found since `/usr/sbin` is not in the default cron `PATH`.

Comment: Hm, `/usr/sbin` is listed in the PATH of  `/etc/crontab`. Is there a different crontab file for root?

Comment: 1) Run `rfkill list all` and make sure your device is not hard blocked … 2) Try adding e.g. a `sleep 30 && ` at the cron line before your command. Your commands might be running early and another service undo it afterwards … 3) IIRC gnome bluetooth app is overriding other bluetooth tools in recent versions so look into that.

Comment: @Pixelcode yes, `sudo crontab -e` edits the file at `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`

Comment: If you don't ever want bluetooth to be enabled, then perhaps a better approach would be to disable or even mask the service?

Comment: @Raffa: Yeah, that's a good idea, though it doesn't seem to have worked yet. I'll try with greater delays, but I'm not too optimistic.

Comment: @stelldriver: Well, sometimes I do want to use Bluetooth to connect my headphones, but I don't want it to be on the whole time, as it drains the battery quite quickly.